# Не работает клон в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, клонирование

У меня проблема, я написал код на клонирование объекта и при клонировании клонов двое и у одного клона неактивны компоненты(RigidBody2, BoxCollider2D и скрипты)

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PickCoinUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int coins;
    public GameObject coin;
    public GameObject coinClone;

    public Transform spawnZone;
    //
    float minX;
    float maxX;
    float minY;
    float maxY;
    //


    private void Start()
    {
        maxX = spawnZone.position.x + spawnZone.localScale.x / 2;
        minX = spawnZone.position.x - spawnZone.localScale.x / 2;
        maxY = spawnZone.position.y + spawnZone.localScale.y / 2;
        minY = spawnZone.position.y - spawnZone.localScale.y / 2;
    }
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (GameObject.FindWithTag("Coin"))
        {
            PickUp();
            Spawn();
        }
    }

    public void PickUp()
    {
            coins++;
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    public void Spawn()
    {
        Vector2 spawnPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY));
            Instantiate(gameObject, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может дело в том, что сначала Вы **удаляете** объект, а потом **копируете/клонируете** этот удаляемый объект?

Comment: Александр Даниловский спасибо, но теперь клонов создаётся 2

Comment: Ты один объект удаляешь и тут же создаёшь точно такой же. Проще будет не удалять, а просто переносить существующий объект в другое место, в spawnPos. Ну и не забыть сделать, то же, что ты в Start делаешь.

Comment: спасибо огромное, но к значению coins пребавляется 2 а не 1